# How do I select last event value of the day in Google Analytic

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to select last event value of the day in Google Analytics.
The problem is that Event Value column shows the sum of all events of the specific date,
but I would like to see only the last one.

How do I select last event value only of the day in Google Analytic?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the use case, or what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi tmerrick, here is a screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/XBykJ.png

There you can see Total events = 3 and Event Value = 5 Avg.Value = 1.67

I would like to get Event Value of the last event.